# SharePoint passing value of text box on click to update list column

Tags: javascript, java, list, textbox, sharepoint-2013

I have a text box on one SP page. Upon click of the submit button, I need the numerical value/input to be sent to a column in a list. I have some coding put together from bits and pieces I've found online, but it doesn't work.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Shipping</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Domestic:</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input id="domesticshippinginput" name="domesticshippinginput" 
type="textbox" /></td>
<td><input name="ADD" id="btnADD" type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
</tr>

</table>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(updateListItem,'sp.js'); 

function updateListItem() {
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = 
clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('CurrentTimeFrame');
var domesticshipping = list.getItemById(1);
listItem.set_item('days', domesticshippinginput);
listItem.update();
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, 
this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
);
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
alert('Item updated successfully!');
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
alert('Could not update item: ' + args.get_message());
}
</script>
```

Where CurrentTimeFrame is the name of the list, domesticshipping is the name of the title of the row, and days is the column in the list that I need to write to. Domesticshipping is the very first item in the list. This is all coded in the same Snippet (not sure if that matters).

Comment: I updated the question, still the same premise, but added coding. I'm not sure if I'm missing changing a variable name in the coding from what I pulled from different sources. I don't have much experience with java. I appreciate any help with this!

Answer (score 0):

You could use rest api to create/update SharePoint list item.

Get the input value by jQuery.[demo thread](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/crud-operation-on-list-items-using-rest-api-services-in-shar/)

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function CreateItem() {
            $.ajax
                ({
                    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('TestList')/items",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify
                        ({
                            __metadata:
                            {
                                type: "SP.Data.TestListListItem"
                            },
                            Title: $('#txtTitle').val()
                        }),
                    headers:
                    {
                        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
                    },
                    success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                        window.location.href = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/Lists/TestList/EditForm.aspx?ID=" + data.d.Id + ""
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        console.log(data.responseJSON.error);
                    }
                });
        }

    </script>
    <div>
        Title:
        <br />
        <input type="text" id="txtTitle" />
        <br />
        <input id="Button1" onclick="CreateItem()" type="button" value="button" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I shall give this a go and see if I can get it to work. Appreciate the help!